# CentOS 6 LEMP update - dependency error issue

Tags: centos6, yum

I have setup a LEMP server following the guide [Install Nginx/PHP-FPM on Fedora 20/19, CentOS/RHEL 6.5/5.10](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).

It's been a while since I did the setup, so I wanted to grab the latest updates from [REMI repository](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/). I ran the following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update
```

I now get these dependency related errors:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * epel: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * extras: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * remi: remi.schlundtech.de
 * updates: centos.mirror1.spango.com
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package chkconfig.x86_64 0:1.3.49.3-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package chkconfig.x86_64 0:1.3.49.3-2.el6_4.1 will be an update
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.5 will be an update
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.107.el6_4.5 will be an update
---> Package gnupg2.x86_64 0:2.0.14-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package gnupg2.x86_64 0:2.0.14-6.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package iputils.x86_64 0:20071127-17.el6_4 will be updated
---> Package iputils.x86_64 0:20071127-17.el6_4.2 will be an update
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.23.2.el6 will be installed
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-358.18.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package kernel-firmware.noarch 0:2.6.32-358.23.2.el6 will be an update
---> Package libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.4.5-9.el6_2.2 will be updated
---> Package libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.4.5-11.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.69-1.el6_4 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.34-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.4.2-1.el6.ngx will be updated
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.4.3-1.el6.ngx will be an update
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-20.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-23.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6.remi.1 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.2-2.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.3-1.el6.remi.1 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.4-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-sqlite.x86_64 0:2.0.0-0.3.svn313074.el6.remi.5 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-sqlite.x86_64 0:2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.13-1.el6_3 will be updated
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.18-1.el6_4 will be an update
---> Package remi-release.noarch 0:6-2.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package remi-release.noarch 0:6.4-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package rsync.x86_64 0:3.0.6-9.el6 will be updated
---> Package rsync.x86_64 0:3.0.6-9.el6_4.1 will be an update
---> Package selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.7.19-195.el6_4.12 will be updated
---> Package selinux-policy.noarch 0:3.7.19-195.el6_4.18 will be an update
---> Package selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:3.7.19-195.el6_4.12 will be updated
---> Package selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:3.7.19-195.el6_4.18 will be an update
---> Package setup.noarch 0:2.8.14-20.el6 will be updated
---> Package setup.noarch 0:2.8.14-20.el6_4.1 will be an update
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2013c-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package tzdata.noarch 0:2013g-1.el6 will be an update
---> Package xinetd.x86_64 2:2.3.14-38.el6 will be updated
---> Package xinetd.x86_64 2:2.3.14-39.el6_4 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-mysql51.x86_64 0:5.1.54-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.2-2.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 0:1.4.4-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-sqlite.x86_64 0:2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.2-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-mongo-1.4.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-sqlite-2.0.0-0.4.svn332053.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Installed: php-common-5.5.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.21-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any idea how to solve these errors? Am I missing a package? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the problem like this:

1. `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update --skip-broken -y`
2. `yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update --nogpgcheck -y` (had a package not signed warning)

Now everything appears to be updated.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted (in order to reduce the number of unanswered questions on this site).

Comment: sure no problem. done.